# ReDoc cannot display a local OpenAPI definition file

Tags: redoc

ReDoc displays a remote `openapi.json` normally:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html>
  <head>
    <title>ReDoc - openapi.json</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <redoc spec-url="https://petstore3.swagger.io/api/v3/openapi.json"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js">/**/</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But if I save `openapi.json` locally

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><html>
  <head>
    <title>ReDoc - openapi.json</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <redoc spec-url="file:///tmp/openapi.json"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js">/**/</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

it shows this error:

```
Something went wrong...
process is not defined

Stack trace

resolve@https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js:8:301803
resolveExternalRef@https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js:8:76499
4182/resolveDocument/<@https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js:8:77225
4182/r</<@https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js:8:74930
4182/r<@https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js:8:74675
resolveDocument@https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js:8:77178
3675/t.bundle/<@https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js:8:33256
3675/r</<@https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js:8:28947
3675/r<@https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js:8:28692
3675/t.bundle@https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js:8:33035
n@https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js:117:579
Mu/</n/e<@https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js:117:1021
Mu/</n/e<@https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js:117:837
n@https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js:117:1040
Mu/</<@https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js:117:1261
Mu/</<@https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js:117:1077
Mu/<@https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js:117:1280
Il@https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js:8:488153
53/t.unstable_runWithPriority@https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js:8:517125
Wo@https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js:8:428837
Rl@https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js:8:487616
4448/Cl/<@https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js:8:487527
D@https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js:8:516186
53/w.port1.onmessage@https://cdn.redoc.ly/redoc/latest/bundles/redoc.standalone.js:8:514909

ReDoc Version: 2.0.0
Commit: 5fb4daa
```

How to display a local OpenAPI definition file with ReDoc?

Comment: Looks like ReDoc requires running a server for working locally: https://redocly.com/docs/redoc/deployment/intro/#how-to-run-redoc-locally

Comment: I`m also trying to run it locally - without success sofar. According to their page it should be possible (https://redocly.com/docs/redoc/deployment/html/#use-redoc-in-html)

Comment: Having the same issue ,also if you inspect the navigator there is a cross origin  problem

Comment: Dont know if we are facing the same issue but i found a solution for it you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78080197/redoc-failed-to-generate-html-template-something-went-wrong-failed-to-fetch

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is with Redocly CLI:

```
npx @redocly/cli preview-docs openapi.json
```

Source: https://redocly.com/docs/cli/commands/preview-docs/

Comment: What if its not possible to install node.js on the server ?

Answer (score 0):

the best solution i found is to download  the standalone javascript file and add it to your springboot app under ressources/static/redoc.standalone.js   and call it directly in your index.html.
and it works like a charm !

you can download it from :https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/redoc@2.1.3/bundles/redoc.standalone.js